# how to use pthread_cond_timedwait with millisecond

Tags: linux, gcc, pthreads

I am trying to use pthread_cond_timedwait for millisecond sleep interval but I am not getting sleep duration. my thread is sleeping more than I have mentioned. below is my implementation. Let me know if i am wrong anywhere.

```
    struct timeval tp;
    struct timespec ts;
    int rc = gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);

    ts.tv_sec = tp.tv_sec;
    ts.tv_nsec = tp.tv_usec * 1000;

    ts.tv_nsec += 30 * 1000000;  //30 is my milliseconds

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtxPlaybackWait);
    pthread_cond_timedwait(&playbackSignal, &mtxPlaybackWait, &ts);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtxPlaybackWait);
```

Comment: can you tell exact time thread is sleeping? does timeout happening?

Comment: timeout happens and sleeping time is always more than the milliseconds I set. Can mutex lock take extra time?

Answer (score 0):

`timespac` might be overflowed and causing timeout.
  Try following:

```
     ts.tv_sec = tp.tv_sec;
     ts.tv_nsec = tp.tv_usec * 1000;  

     ts.tv_nsec += 30 * 1000000; 

     ts.tv_sec += ts.tv_nsec / 1000000000L;  
     ts.tv_nsec = ts.tv_nsec % 1000000000L;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through something like you said. Let me try. will let you know.

Comment: `ts.tv_nsec += 30 * 1000000;` is not a good practice. `+=` would cause overflow. Instead, one should use a `uint64_t` for time addition.

Answer (score 0):

You have an addition of seconds and microseconds on one side, and milliseconds on the other. The result is in seconds and nanoseconds.

If you try to express seconds in nanoseconds, this may overflow quickly: 1 second = 1,000,000,000 nanoseconds, which takes up ~30 bits. An unsigned 32-bit integer value can hold up to ~4 seconds if unsigned (~2 for a signed int) and will overflow beyond that.

Also, I am not sure if all functions behave correctly under all circumstances when passed a struct where the fractional seconds amount to more than a second. I’d expect widely used standard libraries to have done their homework and normalize first (or otherwise ensure correct behavior), but some quickly assembled niche product might not handle such cases properly.

To prevent both the overflow and strange side effects of anomalies, shave off integer seconds wherever you can and store them in the seconds part rather than in the fractional seconds.

Here is a version of your calculation which avoids both these things:

```
gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
/* if msec is 1 s or more, add its integer part to tv_sec */
ts.tv_sec = tp.tv_sec + floor(msec / 1000);
/* for now, these are really µsec, not nsec, to prevent overflow */
ts.tv_nsec = tp.tv_usec + (msec % 1000) * 1000000;
/* if tv_nsec is 1s or more, move integer second part to tv_sec */
ts.tv_sec += floor(ts.tv_nsec / 1000000);
ts.tv_nsec %= 1000000;
/* and finally, convert µsec to nsec */
ts.tv_nsec *= 1000;
```

You might not need `floor` if you are certain that you are operating on integer types (i.e. for `msec` and `ts.tv_nsec`)—in that case, a simple division will do.